# Make the App icon UnFocusable in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry

I have install an application in my device on which I am working. When I open the downloads folder in my device, my app Icon seems focused. 
Now my question is, is it possible to make it un-focusable. As shown in image. please let me know if anyone have some suggestions for this task.[image]

Comment: I'm just curious.  **Why** are you trying to do this?  If your app is supported on non-touch devices, having a non-focusable icon makes it hard/confusing for users to select it.  Even on a touch-screen, I wouldn't think users would like that.  Are you still supplying two icons, to show when the user "rolls over" the icon?

Comment: Hello Nate , actually its a requirement of my client, its required to show the name of the application without Blue background when selected. Is it possible to do that.?

Comment: Hello Eugen, I just need to make my app icon un focusable.

Comment: I don't think you mean "un focusable", you mean "no blue background on the icon". If that's the case then answer below...:)

Comment: Oh...!!I need to learn a-lot,no worry I am learning.:)
Thanxx for correcting me Donturner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the blue background on the icon by specifying a rollover icon which has a non-transparent background in your BlackBerry Application Descriptor here:

[image]

Note that you will not be able to remove the text highlighting underneath the icon because that behaviour is controlled by the OS, which incidentally is a *good thing* because otherwise your users wouldn't know when your app is focussed.